# an error with models.DateField()

Tags: django

I write a django app,but there is error troubling me.
this is the code from my model:

```
class Orders(models.Model):
    checkin = models.DateField()
    checkout = models.DateField()
    total  = models.FloatField()
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.checkin
```

last, I add a record with Django administration,and submit, it return an error: http://dpaste.com/1202450/
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `__unicode__` method must return a unicode string, not a date. You should convert the field:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.checkin)
```

You may want to convert the date to a specific human-readable format instead, using `strftime`.